# При использовании pandas для чтения excel индексация начинается со 2й строчки

Tags: python, pandas

Использую библиотеку pandas для excel файла. Но он почему-то игнорирует первую строку в excel и позволяет обратиться к ячейкам начиная со второй

```
data = pd.read_excel(path, engine='openpyxl')
print(data.iloc[0, 7])
```

В этом случае он выдает значение 2й строчки 7й ячейки. А как обратиться к 1й строчке?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию первая строка считается заголовком. Укажите, что у вас нет заголовка так:

```
data = pd.read_excel(path, header=None, engine='openpyxl')
```